# Liferay MySQL through ssh connection

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ssh, liferay-6

I need to connect my Liferay to a MySQL database through a ssh tunnel.

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=password
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.37:3306/gdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
```

I can't find anything about that.

Comment: What you have tried, and is there any error?  Or simply you want to connect MySQL database using ssh client?

Comment: Check my answer in the post, might be you can able to connect now.

Answer (score 0):

If have any ssh client then you can use the below command to connect to MySQL database.

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -proot
```

Explanation:

```
mysql  -- CLI command that allows to connect a database and perform queries
-h     -- to specify the hostname
localhost  --is the hostname/IP address, remember don't put any space " " between "-h" and "localhost" as above. 
-u     --to specify the username
root   --is a MySQL username
-p     -- to specify the password
rootp  --is the password for MySQL root user, if you don't want to pass the password in CLI then you can leave them as below

MySQL -hlocalhost -uroot -p
```

then it will prompt to enter the password for root user

In your case command will be:

```
mysql -h192.168.1.37 -uroot -ppassword  gdb
```

Comment: And if you don't have any SSH client then you can download a open source client called "putty" from this link:      https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe

Comment: I have posted another solution, check it out, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step configuration for Liferay and MySQL:

To configure your Liferay portal with MySQL SGBD, follow these instructions :

**Downloading the jdbc Driver**

For MySQL, there is no need to download the jdbc driver. When Liferay detects you want to use MySQL, it will automatically include the driver (mysql.jar) in your $TOMCAT_HOME/lib/ext.

**Creating the blank database**

Create a blank database using the UTF-8 encoding and give it a name. Let’s consider that the created database is “lportal”.

**Updating portal-ext.properties**

Open your portal-ext.properties file and past the following lines :

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=root
```

Set the correct username and password to connect to your database.

**Check the configuration**

During the server start, you can check that Liferay started with the appropriate dialect by looking for the following lines in your server log console/file:

```
14:23:20,480 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for MySQL 5
14:23:20,574 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

If you go back to your database, you will see that it’s now populated by about 180 data tables that Liferay created on startup.

[Reference Link for more over Connecting Liferay to MySQL](http://roufid.com/liferay-database-configuration/#MySQL)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to connect remote database using ssh within Liferay, but you can try to use JDBC instead. If JDBC is not enabled on database installed system then ask DBA to allow access MySQL remotely.

Comment: What is "MySQL SGBD"?

Comment: It's nothing, in French, we say SGBD (Système Gestion de Base de Données) instead of DBMS (DataBase Management System)

Comment: Yes, I think so.